# MongoDB on Cloud - Jmeter Connectivity Not Working

Tags: mongodb, jmeter, cloud, connection-timeout

I am trying to connect to a cloud server that is running a mongodb instance. I am getting below exception when trying to connect from Jmeter.

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketChannelStream.open(SocketChannelStream.java:63) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishTimedConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:1143) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.blockingConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:1181) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:97) ~[?:?]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketChannelStream.initializeSocketChannel(SocketChannelStream.java:72) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketChannelStream.open(SocketChannelStream.java:60) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.9.1.jar:?]
... 3 more

I am able to connect to the Cloud server using VPN and SSL public certificate, but not through JMeter. Can someone please help ?

I tried connecting using a JMeter connection script :

```
import com.mongodb.*

import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

import org.bson.Document;

import java.util.Arrays;

try {
    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .applyToClusterSettings {builder -> 
            builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(vars.get("mongoHost"),vars.get("mongoPort").toInteger())))}
        .build();
    
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
    
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(vars.get("databaseName"));
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(vars.get("collectionName"));
    
    vars.putObject("collection", collection);
    
    return "Connected to " + vars.get("collectionName");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

All the fieldnames have been verified, but I am not sure if I have to enter ssl auth details in the connection url.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add at least the next line to your script so [MongoClientSettings](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.9.1/com/mongodb/MongoClientSettings.html) would attempt to create an SSL connection:

```
.applyToSslSettings(builder -> builder.enabled(true))
```

The certificate needs to be put into a [Java Keystore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_KeyStore) and JMeter needs to be configured to use the keystore via special [system properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization).

More information: [MongoDB Driver Tutorials > Connect to MongoDB > TLS/SSL](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/driver/tutorials/ssl/)